# Gigabyte GA-H170M-D3H boot loop power issues and no display

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

Since I updated my BIOS version to the latest version on the GIGABYTE motherboard manufacturer's website (F23F version) I started experiencing a series of different and strange problems

Then when I restarted the computer there was no display on the screen. I had to disconnect the power from the computer completely for a whole day and plug it in and only then would the computer come on with a display on the screen.. but even then it would only come on once when I restarted the computer there was no longer a display on the screen a phenomenon very strangeI ignored the very fact that upgrading the BIOS version causes the problem and I started looking for other solutions. I thought to myself ok, maybe it's the power supply so I went and bought a brand new power supply. When I connect the new power supply, the computer performs a LOOP of restarts for itself and basically turns itself off and turns itself on again... and does not continue to the operating system

In the last few days, after I installed the new power supply I bought and when the computer was doing restart loops there was still a display on the screen and I could enter the BIOS in BIOS mode the computer could work for hours but when it exits the BIOS and tries to continue to Any BOOT even USB or to the hard disk the computer just immediately does a loop of restarting.

Now after few days in the current situation... there is no display on the screen and the computer just does loops of restarting itself I notice the fans working and then turning off and restarting itself again...

I am quite discouraged and now I will list what attempts I tried to solve the problem but without success.

- I tried to connect the screen to the video card directly
- I tried to connect the screen to the video card built into the board
- I tried removing the processor and reinserting it..
- I tried to remove all the memories and leave only one memory and switch between them
- I tried to remove the battery from the board
- I tried to put the JUMPER on the board on the CMOS
- I tried to clear the contacts of the memories
- I tried replacing power cables. of screen..
- I replaced a new power supply with an ANTEC CSK 750 model
- I tried disconnecting all the connections from the board and all the SATA cables that are connected.
- I even tried to make sure that the new power supply I bought was really working... so I took another old computer that has a 500 watt power supply
  And I connected to it the power supply of the new 750 watt that I bought and indeed the supply is working and there was a display and everything worked...
- Funny as it sounds I even tried replacing the motherboard battery

My specs:

- motherboard - GA-H170M-D3H (gigabyte)
- 4X memory sticks of 8GB total 32GB --- memory model TED48G2400C16BK (DDR4 2400)
- cpu - I5-6600
- nvidia geforce 1080p
  750W psu (ANTEC CSK 750W)

---

**Update**: I was able to clear cmos with two wires, apparently this time I did it well, but at the moment I get to the POST screen, and then if I press the BIOS entry option, I can stay there for an unlimited time, but if I exit the BIOS, the computer continues reboots itself with a display and then goes back to the BOOT loop until I enter the BIOS menu again, that means I'm back to the beginning only now if it's possible to see the BIOS

Please look at these two screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Now the question is how do I continue from here? The computer loops with BIOS and cannot reach the operating system and cannot BOOT from USB